# css perspective difference in chrome/safari

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, webkit

I've experience a weird bug between Chrome and Safari using css -webkit-perspective.
Using same perspective, the whole 3D scene seems zoomed in Safari.

Take a look by yourself:
http://clients.dominic-mercier.com/experiments/css-perspective-bug.html

Anyone know on to fix it?

Comment: This is weird indeed, seems like a Chrome bug to me. If you take out -webkit-perspective in Safari they are the same size, but without perspective of course. Nice work btw!

Comment: Any chance you have this code still lying around and you can throw it somewhere not dead?

Comment: @RandallB: Sorry, this post is too old. Can't find this file anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.
The problem seem to be related to -webkit-transform-origin which seem buggy in Chrome.
I've solve my problem by using -webkit-transform: translateZ instead of -webkit-transform-origin.

Hope it will help someone one day.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me - older versions of Chrome didn't support -webkit-perspective, so check that you're on the most recent version.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and Safari are you using?

Comment: I'm also using Chrome 14.0.835.202
Safari is version 5.0.5